# Not able to perform PUT request in my react js application

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-hooks, jsonplaceholder

I'm working on the CRUD operations that are to be performed in an application using JSON placeholder API. I want to update the data of the API using the PUT request and display it back on my front end. I'm actually fetching the data from the users endpoint. I'm not able to perform the PUT request and I'm not understanding whether or not to set the array after performing the PUT request. I keep getting an error that is: userData.map() is not a function after clicking on save changes. I know that I'm setting a single object to the array after the fetching operation which is logically incorrect. I'm using Axios at present, also used fetch(), but no use. Nothing works! Please help me out with this one. I'm attaching the code below. "handleSave" is the function where I'm performing the changes.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
    import axios from 'axios';

    function Table() {

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    const [clickOnEdit, setClickOnEdit] = useState(false);
    const [index, setIndex] = useState("");
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState("")
    const [website, setWebsite] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((res) => {
        setUserData(res.data);
    })
    },[])

    const handleAddRow = () => {
        setUserData([...userData, 
            {
                id: uuidv4(), 
                name: "name", 
                username: "username",
                email: "email",
                phone: "phone",
                website: "website"
            }
        ])
    }

    const handleDelete = (item) => {
        const id = item;
        setUserData(userData.filter((individualItem) => individualItem.id !== id));
    }

    const handleEdit = (item) => {
        const id = item;
        setIndex(id);
        setClickOnEdit(true);
    }


    const handleSave = (item) => {

        setClickOnEdit(false);
        axios.put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${item}`,
        {
            name: name, 
            username: username, 
            email: email, 
            phone: phone, 
            website: website
        })
        .then((res) => {
            setUserData(res.data);
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Phone</th>
                        <th>Website</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <button onClick={(e) => handleAddRow(e)}>Add row</button>
            {userData.map((items, id) => (
                <div key={id} >
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            {clickOnEdit ? 
                                <div>
                                    {index === id ?
                                    <div>
                                        <td><input value={name} name="name" onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} /></td>
                                        <td><input value={username} name="username" onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} /></td>
                                        <td><input value={email} name="email" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value) } /></td>
                                        <td><input value={phone} name="phone" onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} /></td>
                                        <td><input value={website} name="website" onChange={(e) => setWebsite(e.target.value)} /></td>
                                        <button onClick={() => handleSave(items.id)} >Save entry</button>
                                    </div>
                                    :
                                    <div>
                                        <td>{items.name}</td>
                                        <td>{items.username}</td>
                                        <td>{items.email}</td>
                                        <td>{items.phone}</td>
                                        <td>{items.website}</td>
                                        <button onClick={(e) => handleEdit(items.id, e)} >Edit</button>
                                        <button onClick={() => handleDelete(items.id)}>Delete</button>
                                    </div>
                                    }
                                </div>
                                :
                                <div>
                                    <td>{items.name}</td>
                                    <td>{items.username}</td>
                                    <td>{items.email}</td>
                                    <td>{items.phone}</td>
                                    <td>{items.website}</td>
                                    <button onClick={(e) => handleEdit(items.id, e)} >Edit</button>
                                    <button onClick={() => handleDelete(items.id)}>Delete</button>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </tr> 
                    </table>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: just make sure you are only updating user resource with ids up to 10.

Comment: yes @aitchkhan, I performing the function within the id's range. But nothing works. I think I have done something wrong within the div scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you will get is an object, so try to replace that id with the res object.

```js
 const handleSave = (item) => {

        setClickOnEdit(false);
        axios.put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${item}`,
        {
            name: name, 
            username: username, 
            email: email, 
            phone: phone, 
            website: website
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setUserData(
            userData.map((user) =>
              user.id === res.data.id - 1 ? res.data : user
            )
          );
        })
    }
```

Comment: I made the changes sir. Am I doing anything wrong within the entire <div> section? Although there is no error, the logic doesn't work..

Comment: Whoaa!! Thank you very much sir! It worked! I'll try to understand the logic. Can I please contact you if I had any doubts in the coming days?

Comment: You're implementation is really messy. Try to have a unique id. I did `res.data.id - 1` which was a hack to get to the right element. Try getting to the right element first with proper ids without the hack. Next, try to clear off all the warnings on the console. You'll learn a lot just by clearing those console warnings.

Comment: Got it sir! I was trying to pinpoint the item that I wanted to work with, but wasn't able to reach that point.

Answer (score 1):

First thing - You should always check the status code of your response. I mean if it is success then what status code it returns Normally get request gives 200. If you do not check it then If error occurs then It will also execute the below line

```
setUserData(res.data);
```

Secondly as the `userData` is an array so you should set the updated response like below after the put

```js
setUserData([...userData.filter(element => element.id === res.data.id - 1 ? res.data : element)])
```

Comment: Hi @moshfiqrony sir ! Thank you very much for the answer. I made the changes. Now the error is gone, but the changes are not getting reflected on the frontend sir. What do I do?

Comment: I have updated the answer Do this setUserData([...userData.filter(element => element.id === item ? res.data : element)])

Comment: Can you console log of your state has the updated data

Comment: Using index as a key is also not a best approach use ```items.id``` as key

Comment: yes sir! I did it just now. I console logged the array after I saw your message. The values didn't change sir

Comment: sir, can I contact you elsewhere? like through discord or Gmail?

Comment: That mean your API is not returning the updated data. Console log your API response

Comment: I console logged the API response sir. The original data is getting displayed. But nothing with the updated one.

Comment: Sir I'm not able to send message cuz my reputation score is low

Comment: If your api is not updating or returning updated data then it's the API problem